# how do i add a label to these boxes without changing the format of the boxes and size?

Tags: python, tkinter, project

**this is the code that im working on and i need to be corrected
**

```
def search():
    # Add search functionality here
    print("Searching...")

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Unidirect")

# Label for Main Menu with grey background
main_menu_label = tk.Label(root, text="Unidirect", font=("Helvetica", 30), bg="maroon", padx=root.winfo_reqwidth())
main_menu_label.pack(pady=20, fill="x")

# Log Out button in the top-left
logout_button = tk.Button(main_menu_label, text="Log Out", command=logout)
logout_button.pack(side="left", padx=10)

# Search button in the top-right
search_button = tk.Button(main_menu_label, text="Search", command=search)
search_button.pack(side="right", padx=10)

# Grey box for Notifications in the top left
notifications_box = tk.Frame(root, bg="navy", height=300, width=500)
notifications_box.place(x=50, y=100)

# Grey box for Cart in the top right
cart_box = tk.Frame(root, bg="navy", height=300, width=500)
cart_box.place(x=1400, y=100)

# Grey box for Items in the bottom middle
items_box = tk.Frame(root, bg="navy", height=300, width=500)
items_box.place(x=770, y=600)

# Run the Tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
object.pack_propagate(False)
```

So for example:

```
# Grey box for Cart in the top right
cart_box = tk.Frame(root, bg="navy", height=300, width=500)
cart_box.place(x=1400, y=100)
cart_box.pack_propagate(False)
```

Comment: it doesn't work it send back errors

Comment: can you update the post with the code you have tired